# Death of a worker on the site during construction- should the house warming ceremony be postponed?

Tags: death

If one of the construction workers died accidentally on the site while building the house, should the house owners postpone the house warming ceremony?

Comment: I have just removed the personal angle from ur Q so that it can be reopened. See if u'r OK with the edit or not.

Comment: @Rickross, Originally I was first to upvote this Qn, but it seemed that the Qn was indeed off-topic. Even with the new edits, I think the Qn is still quite off-topic, because it asks about a very specific scenario, which may not relate to Hinduism directly. I think we have to come up with a title, which is quite generic and reaches to the broader audience. Such as, *"What are the effects of accidental death of a related person, on a house warming ceremony?"*. The body may contain kinds of "related person". But that will change the Qn altogether. :-)

Comment: @iammilind I think the current one is just fine. Death is considered as inauspicious. So scriptures might have some injunctions on the situation on hand. Also i just removed the personal things from the Q and which was why it was closed.